# NullPointerException with bidimensional Object array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm  having some problems with Object arrays. I've made up my own object which only has an empty constructor, a constructor which initializes its two instance variables with paramaters and get/set methods.

I initiliaze the array like this:

```
private Bara[][] card = new Bara[3][4];
```

and I'm trying to fill in the object's variables like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
         card[i][j].setName(name);
         card[i][j].setSide(side);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private Bara[][] card = new Bara[3][4];
```

It just creates a two-d array for the referrences of Bara, but no Bara objects.

Thus, you need to create actual Bara Objects in your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
     card[i][j] = new Bara(name, side); //If such constructor exists.
}
}
```

Comment: You sir are a gentlemen and a scholar. Thank you, this fixed my problem.